# displaying Android tab layout outside of a tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have in my application tabbed activities.
Now I want from one of those tabbed activities to start a new activity that isn't one of the tabbed activities (a sort of sub screen) but still be able to see the tab layout, just without any tab selected obviously.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. But it is possible to make such effect. Set an extra tab in your tabHost for the activity you want to start. Make this extra tab invisible and when you want to start the activity set the tab as current.